# Optimize MySQL query performance

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-performance

**My solution:**
With @Alex's help

I added 3 new columns to the table, name them year(YYYY), month(YYYY-MM) and day(YYYY-MM-DD) and add 3 indexes into the table:

```
alter table vaadin_table add index (year, status);
alter table vaadin_table add index (month, status);
alter table vaadin_table add index (day, status);
```

Now my queries are:

```
select year,status, count(1) from vaadin_table group by year, status;
select month,status, count(1) from vaadin_table group by month, status;
select day,status, count(1) from vaadin_table group by day, status;
```

I can get the result in 2 seconds! Thanks for all your help, really appreciated!
**It seems like Mysql doesnt support functions on the indexed columns which makes my original post queries did not work**

**Edit:**
Thanks for all replies.

To make my question more clear. I need to get the daily/monthly/yearly stats from the table.

Therefore I use below to group by daily/monthly/yearly data in order:

substring(entry_date,1, 11)  --->  YYYY-MM-DD

substring(entry_date,1, 7)  --->  YYYY-MM

substring(entry_date,1, 4)  --->  YYYY

All those 3 columns makes my queries slow.

**Original Question:**
I have a 2.7 million rows table. It contains 3 columns: name, status and entry_date(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table 
(id integer not null auto_increment primary key, 
name char(20) not null, status char(20) not null, 
entry_date datetime default 0);
```

My purpose is to get the daily numbers of per status:

```
SELECT substring(entry_date, 1, 11), status, count(1) 
FROM test_table 
GROUP BY
substring(entry_date, 1, 11), status;
```

It works fine but takes about 10 seconds to return the result.

To optimize it, I add index to the table as:

```
ALTER table test_table ADD INDEX test_index(entry_date, status);
```

I read some similar questions on line, all suggest adding index based on the group by order. But it doesn't help for my case. Is it because I am using substring of entry_date?

Please help, thanks

Comment: your entry date is date time value why your doing sub string on it this will slow down the performance any reason ?

Comment: why `substring(entry_date, 1, 11)` but not just `entry_date` ?

Comment: You are correct; using any function on an indexed field in a condition or grouping results in ignoring the index (for that condition or grouping). Unfortunately, this will even include using CAST or other date functions you could use to get the date of the datetime field.

Comment: substring(entry_date, 1, 11) is getting the YYYY-MM-DD which ignore the HH:MM:SS part

Comment: Yep using any function on the indexed column results in ignorance of index.

Comment: you can use date(entry_date) without that substring but with this function still it will have a impact .

Comment: so just set `GROUP BY
DATE(entry_date)`

Comment: I'd caution against using `year`, `month`, and `day` (without any sort of prefix, like `entry_year`) as field names since they are keywords. While they are not actually _reserved_, it can cause some confusion, especially when dealing with date data; it may not be 100% perfectly clear how things like `now() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR` will be interpreted.

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks for your suggestion, I renamed the columns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT entry_date, status, count(1) 
FROM test_table 
GROUP BY
DATE(entry_date), status;
```

or even better add extra column with `DATE` type

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD COLUMN entry_date1 DATE;
UPDATE test_table  SET entry_date1=DATE(entry_date);

SELECT entry_date1, status, count(1) 
FROM test_table 
GROUP BY
entry_date1, status;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I updated my question to make it more precise.

Comment: your update change nothing. any function called against every record breaks the performance and will not use any index

Comment: any suggestions about how can I solve such scenarios? much appreciated

Comment: that is why I ANSWERED did you try?

Comment: I was about to post similar answer. What alex suggested is correct actually. Make three different columns (as per your need), index them and then use them with `where` clause. MySQL doesn't support Function-based Indexes. (Use Oracle maybe ?)

Comment: @Alex  thanks for your answer. I am not allowed to modify the production table, therefore I will duplicate one on my virtual machine and try your suggestion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Alex  Thanks, it works after I add 3 columns, and add 3 new-added columns with status indexes, it can return the result is 2 sec

Comment: good for you! good luck with your project. and check how you `insert/update` new records into this table, now you need to update new column as well.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize it, my suggestions are as below

change query

```
SELECT date(entry_date), status, count(1) 
FROM test_table 
GROUP BY
status,date(entry_date);
```

then create index in following column order

```
ALTER table test_table ADD INDEX test_index( status,entry_date);
```

Comment: then it will utilize status index when it perform group by